# How to interpret Fisher Test?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, independence, fishers-exact-test, association-measure

How do I interpret the odds ratio for this fisher test output in R?

...below is my matrix that I input into fisher.test in R:

[image]

...and below this is the output of the test in R:

[image]

Comment: What specifically is the part you do not understand?

Comment: How to interpret the odds ratio in this case @mdewey

Answer (score 2):

That p-value is for the null hypothesis of independence between the two categorical variables.  We reject the null of independence here.

For the odds ratio, if the confidence interval contains one, we fail to reject the null hypothesis of independence.

As you can see, we reject the null of independence since the confidence interval doesn't contain 1.

Update: The section below is a general description to help you understand what the odds ratio is and why a value close to 1 means we don't have evidence against independence (that is, loosely speaking, why a value close to 1 should be associated in your mind with independence)

Odds ratio $\theta$ is defined as $\theta = \frac{n_{11}/n_{12}}{n_{21}/n_{22}}=\frac{n_{11}n_{22}}{n_{12}n_{21}}$.

If the ratio of counts in row 1 is very similar to the ratio of counts in row 2, the odds ratio will be close to 1.  In the case that $\theta$ is close to one, the "row you are in" doesn't seem to affect the column count very much.  Hence, there is a (suggested) lack of association, which is to say (a suggestion of) independence.

Comment: While the proportions are not all that far from equal, at those sample sizes the null hypothesis of independence is not remotely tenable; the effect may not be all that strong (on the other hand it's not really weak either -- the second column is not close) but your last sentence is clearly at odds with the rejection of the null. There's no suggestion of independence; there's a clear negative association between cfm and meeting.

Comment: I intended for my last comments to be a general description of the odds ratio.  I'll make that clearer by editing it.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are suggesting. Since the odds ratio is far from 1.0, does this imply a weak association? Is my sample size too small to really make a conclusion? @Glen_b

Comment: @Jules No, your sample size is not to small and you really can make the conclusion, that "meeting" and "cfm" are not Independent.

Answer (score 0):

The 95%-CI for the odds ratio spans from 0.000 to 0.6844, thus an odds ratio of 1.0 is far off and you can reject the null hypothesis, that the values in the contingency table are independent. p = 7.9e-12 means $7.9 \times 10^{-12}$, so very close to zero. Conventionally, the test result is considered 'significant' if p < 0.05. Here p is smaller than that by many magnitudes.

Comment: I see that 0 is the CI, but what does an odds ratio of 0 mean? @Bernhard

Comment: @jules An odds ratio of 1 means, that the odds of "meeting" are the same, no matter what "cfm" or the other way around. The stronger the odds of meeting are influenced by cfm (or the other way around) the more the odds ratio will tend towards zero or towards infinity. The important question is not, wheter 0.00000001 is in the confidence interval but that 1.000 is not within the confidence Intervall. Therefor you have proven the null hypothesis wrong and consider your test result "significant". 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio

Comment: @jules note that the lower limit is zero because you specified a directional hypothesis and zero is the lower bound. If you had specified the other alternative the upper bound would have been infinity. Only if you ask for a two-sided interval will both bounds be estimated.